# Método show do controller interceptando rota sem parâmetro

Tags: laravel

Olá, no meu sistema tenho uma model PhotoGalleryCategory que possui um auto relacionamento. Para facilitar minha vida no método create (controller resource), adicionei um parâmetro para receber o id da categoria pai. Se pai for null, quer dizer que aquela categoria não tem pai e ela seria raiz.

Eliminei o método create da rota resource e adicionei uma nova passando o parâmetro opcional pro método. Caso eu entre na rota e passe o parâmetro, funciona normalmente, caso eu não passe parâmetro sou direcionado paro o método show. O /create é entendido como parâmetro.

Abaixo está meu código dessa situação:

```
 Route::resource('/galleryCategory', 'PhotoGalleryCategoryController')->except(['create']);
    Route::get('/galleryCategory/create/{category?}', 'PhotoGalleryCategoryController@create')->name('galleryCategory.create');

public function create($id = null)
    {
        $entity = null;
        $fields = 'app.models.photoGalleryCategory.categoryCreateEdit';
        $action = 'galleryCategory.store';
        $parent = $this->repository->show($id);
        return view('app.templates.form', compact('entity', 'fields', 'action', 'parent'));
    }
```

Alguém sabe proceder como evitar esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando o verbo **GET** e por isso está sendo redirecionado para o método *show*,
altere para **POST**.

```
Route::post('/galleryCategory/create/{category?}', 'PhotoGalleryCategoryController@create')->name('galleryCategory.create');
```

Comment: nesse caso não aconteceria a mesma coisa porém com o método store?

Comment: Não porque o método store por padrão recebe um request como parâmetro, já o método show recebe apenas um ID que no caso é o que você está passando.